# How to display a PropertySheet on two columns

Tags: javafx, controlsfx, propertysheet

I need to display a Propertysheet (ControlFx) on two columns like this

```
property1  value1     property4  value4
property2  value2     property5  value5
property3  value3.
```

The first idea was to use two property sheets. But we don't like it. So we search a way to do it with only one property sheet.

Thanks for your help

I have this : 
https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/propertySheet.PNG
(I can't display image without 10 reputation...)

I want this : 
https://preview.ibb.co/kmZq4z/One_Property_Sheet_Two_Columns.png

Comment: what is propertySheet? not a core fx class ... please clarify what exactly you are after, best with a [mcve] and how that is different from what you want to achieve

Comment: Ok i put some links to images of what I need and what i want